# My PC turns on every time I plug something into my outlets

Tags: windows-11, desktop-computer, gaming

Whenever I plug something into my outlets my PC wakes up from sleep. I tried moving my cords to different outlets. and the same thing occurred. My pc also wakes up if I plug a usb into one of my outlets. I have tried so many things and it turns out that everything I plug into any outlet will trigger my pc to turn on. My pc is connected to a UPS that should prevent it from happening but didn't change anything. Can someone help me solve the problem?

Comment: Put the PC on a different circuit to spread the load a bit.

Comment: what do you mean Different circuit?

Comment: If you have many things on one circuit, that may be causing the interference to the gaming machine. Different circuit means different residence electrical outlet.

Comment: ok. The only things connected to my circuit is My Alexa, My camera. I have an extension cord running up my bed to connect to my led lights and a Diffuser. And then my PC is connected to a ups as well as my monitor which is connected to the wall. I got this PC 2 days ago. because my last pc kept tripping my breaker every time I turned it on from sleep

Comment: It is probably all that stuff that is waking the computer

Comment: but the weird thing is that all those things are always plugged into the wall. The only thing that is triggering it. Is if i plug in a cord. for instance. I can plug in my lightening cord into a usb Brick which is connected to the wall and my pc turns on from that. I am trying something. I am plugging my usb brick into a extension cord that is plugged into a different outlet

Comment: Get an electrician to install a separate wall outlet for the computer.

Comment: Could it be that every time I plug something into my outlets. It makes a Sudden voltage change. Therefore Triggering my pc to wake. because whenever I keep everything plugged in. Nothing happens and my pc stays  in sleep mode.

Comment: This is why I recommend a separate circuit

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: You need an electrician to do this

Comment: ok. I'll try to do that. Thanks for the help

Comment: `I plug a usb into one of my outlets` ... usb what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electronic circuitry is / can be sensitive to voltage fluctuations.

A separate residence circuit will reduce and possibly eliminate such fluctuations.

I recommend a separate circuit installed by a qualified electrician

Answer (score 0):

That sounds as if your electrical outlets are all on the same circuit-breaker and that circuit is close to being overloaded. Or there is bad wiring on that circuit.
This can cause voltage fluctuations when you plug in something/switch something on.

Normally the UPS should isolate the PC from this (if it is a decent one), but if you have the UPS also connected to the PC by USB (to monitor the UPS) the UPS will alert the PC that there is a power-issue and by doing that will wake the PC from sleep.

Overloaded electrical circuits are BAD. Bad wiring is even WORSE.
Get someone knowledgeable about electricity involved to check your house.